# save first form POST value when another form is click

Tags: php

When i click on Reserved, $page = Reserved. But when I click on another form like GO the $page value will return back to Schedule.

I want to retain the value of $page if it is click on Reserved and click GO $page is still equal to Reserve.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['page'])){
    $page = $_POST['page']; 
}
else $page = 'Schedule';

echo $page;
?>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="page" value="Schedule" />
    <input type="submit" name="page" value="Resereved" />
</form>
<br /><br />
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submission" value="GO" />
</form>
```

Please help I'm stuck with this for 1 day..

Comment: Did you post this in another question a few hours ago? I remember commenting on a question just like this, but now I can't find it. Was it deleted?

Comment: Yes..
but i just type in the code here and type some errors.
someone says to correct the code first.

Sorry for that. Its my first time here...
hope you understand.

Comment: You should edit the question, not start a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['page'])){
    $page = $_POST['page'];
    $_SESSION['page'] =  $page;
}
if(isset($_SESSION['page']))
{
$page = $_SESSION['page'];

}
else $page = 'Schedule';

echo $page;

?>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="page" value="Schedule" />
    <input type="submit" name="page" value="Resereved" />
</form>
<br /><br />
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submission" value="GO" />
</form>
```

use sessions

Comment: Thanks a lot... it works...
its my first time here and I receive a good answer...
COOL...

Comment: Pleasure my friend :) i am happy if that was usefull for you

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    if(isset($_POST['page'])){
 (isset($_POST['page'])) ? '$page = $_POST['page']' : 'Schedule';
 }

 echo $page;
```

Comment: Although it doesn't work you give me a great idea to minimize the line of the first answer from above..